# Exclude several elements out of HTML using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to get some names in a webpage to use them later in the code.

```
content = requests.get("http://serpadres.com/bebe/los-200-nombres-latinos-mas-populares-de-los-ultimos-tiempos/52175/").content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, features="html.parser")
for tag in soup.find_all("br"):

    print("{0}: {1}".format(tag.name, tag.text))
```

I tried this and it did print all the names but also the br tags, being the result:

```
br: 
br: 
br: 
br: 
br: 
br: 
br: 
br: 
VERY LONG LIST OF NAMES
br: 
br: 
br: 
br: 
br: 
br: 
br: 
br: 
br: 
br:
```

and many and many more br:. How can I exclude those and also convert the name to strings?

Comment: Well you did ask it to print `tag.name`  Did you try to just print `tag.text`?

Comment: Yeah you're right, now it doesn't print the br. But now there are blank spaces instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if it's a name or just blank space by adding this line:

```
if tag.get_text() != '':
```

The code would then look like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pip._vendor import requests

mylist = []
content = requests.get("http://serpadres.com/bebe/los-200-nombres-latinos-mas-populares-de-los-ultimos-tiempos/52175/").content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, features="html.parser")
for tag in soup.find_all('br'):
    if tag.get_text() != '':
        print(tag.get_text())
```